# NodeJS EventSource with https proxy doesn't work

Tags: node.js, https, proxy

We have a client which connects to the server. The server can be accessed both: http and https. 
Https server contains CA certified SSL key. 
Since the client is running behind a corporate proxy, we used the following command:

```
const events = this.proxy ? new EventSource(this.source, { proxy: this.proxy }) : new EventSource(this.source)
```

So, the current command works only when connecting to http://server.
If we try to connect to the https://server, the following error received:

```
Event { type: 'error', status: 400, message: 'Bad Request' }
```

So we tried to set:

```
const events = this.proxy ? new EventSource(this.source, {https: {proxy: this.proxy, rejectUnauthorized: false} } ) : new EventSource(this.source)
```

or

```
const events = this.proxy ? new EventSource(this.source, {https: {proxy: this.proxy} } ) : new EventSource(this.source)
```

In both cases, we got a TIME OUT error.

Is there something we are missing? How should we set https connection behind proxy?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use 'global-agent' or 'global-tunnel-ng' packages:

```
// Support working behind a corporate proxy
    const MAJOR_NODEJS_VERSION = parseInt(process.version.slice(1).split('.')[0], 10);

    if (MAJOR_NODEJS_VERSION >= 10) {
  // `global-agent` works with Node.js v10 and above. Proxy env should be defined "export GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8080"
      require('global-agent').bootstrap()
    } else {
  // `global-tunnel-ng` works only with Node.js v10 and below. Uses npm proxy settings
      require('global-tunnel-ng').initialize()
    }   

    const events = new EventSource(this.source)
```

Read here for more info: https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-agent